# Загрузка файла и его сохранение

Tags: php

Есть код html:

```
<form action="/" method="post" class="form-control" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введите текст"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
            <input type="file" name="file"><br>
            <div class="error"><?=  $option['message']?></div>
            <button class="btn" id="send">Добавить</button>
        </form>
```

Есть код php:

```
move_uploaded_file($file['file']['tmp_name'], '/public/img/'.$file['file']['name']);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO items (id, text, img, belongs) VALUES (NULL, :text, :img, :belongs)';
$query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['text' => $text, 'img' => $file['file']['name'], 'belongs' => $email]);
```

Сайт построен на MVC.
Как я понял файл он получает, а сохраняет новые картинки через раз и не понятно по какому принципу: почему anime.jpg он не загружает, а img.jpg загружает.
Я думаю что проблема в `$file['file']['tmp_name']` потому что: в БД имя файла записывается, а на сервере файл не сохраняется, но я точно не понимаю в чём проблема, помогите пж.

Comment: Сюда $_FILES['file']['error']  смотрите? может, у него размер велик

Comment: splash58, попробовал, вывелась двойка. Что это значит?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: splash58, а теперь когда увеличил размер файла в html, ошибок стало 0, а файл также не загружается

Comment: `/public/img/` это путь от корня файловой системы. Я сомневаюсь, что у тебя есть права туда писать, и сомневаюсь, что там есть такая папка.

Comment: картинки записываются туда через раз: какие-то записываются а какие-то нет

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решён